# Looping through each keypace and get table names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, cql

I've written below code,I'm trying to loop through each Key space and get the tables.Could anyone help me on this.

```
 #! /bin/bash
    ## Description   : Cassandra
    Host_name = something
    log_file="/home/Cassandra/log_file.log"
    echo "Select keyspace_name from system_schema.Keyspaces; exit" | cqlsh      Host_name; > $log_file
    for Keyspace_name in `echo "Select keyspace_name from system_schema.Keyspaces; exit" | cqlsh $Host_name`;  do
       echo $Keyspace_name
       echo "select table_name from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name ='$Keyspace_name'; exit" | cqlsh $HOST_NAME
done
exit
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Why is there a semicolon just before redirection of output on this line ... **echo "Select keyspace_name from system_schema.Keyspaces; exit" | cqlsh      Host_name; > $log_file** ? Is the intention to empty out the log_file.log?